# Android 4.0+/Activities Life Cycles

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

I make easy app for test functions like onCreate(), onStart, etc. Each function make you own log. And start test.

- a) When app is started - onCreate, then onStart and onResume.
- b) When press collapse all window button - onPause and onStop.
- c) When select app from list - onRestart, then onStart and onResume.
- d) When press Back button - onPause, onStop and onDestroy.

---

Here's my questions:

1. Why onResume method is called when I execute my app? (in a)
2. Why onPause and onStop methods are called together? (in b)
3. Why in C called three methods instead onRestart, or onResume? (in c)
4. Why onDestroy method is called? (in d)

---

P.S.: Sorry for english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [Android lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

[image]

You can see the answers to your questions by following the chart.

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry for noob question. even ashamed for it